JVM Native memory tracking - mmap vs malloc
Im currently debugging JVM app running in container.
I have enabled JVM Native memory tracking. When looking at the report, I can see that there is memory which is committed, reserved and malloc + mmap.
As far as I have seen malloc size + mmap size == committed memory.
Does anyone know what is the malloc and mmap size ?
I think that it just shows what kernel functions were used to allocate the memory, but Im not sure and I couldn't find any docs.
Im attaching the example report of my app.
Native Memory Tracking:

(Omitting categories weighting less than 1KB)

Total: reserved=1744170KB, committed=399746KB
       malloc: 69218KB #667376
       mmap:   reserved=1674952KB, committed=330528KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=131072KB, committed=131072KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=131072KB, committed=131072KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1050819KB, committed=16515KB)
                            (classes #23646)
                            (  instance classes #22064, array classes #1582)
                            (malloc=2243KB #51615)
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=14272KB)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=131072KB, committed=92160KB)
                            (    used=91882KB)
                            (    waste=278KB =0.30%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=14272KB)
                            (    used=13897KB)
                            (    waste=375KB =2.63%)


As far as I know, malloc size should refer the actual memory the JVM requested (and received) from the OS while mmap should be the memory used for memory-mapped files (or similar). Memory-mapping allows to "map" a file to a section in memory and then access the fily by writing to/reading from that memory section.

re: "I couldn't find any docs" – does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/troubleshoot/diagnostic-tools.html#GUID-1F53A50E-86FF-491D-A023-8EC4F1D1AC77

The C malloc() function is used to allocate a block of memory. It depends on how many times is used and for which sizes. Have you searched "malloc"?
